# How concurrency/locking works on documents while passing mongoDB aggregation pipeline

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

Consider we have two collection `coll1` and `coll2`. I am applying some aggregation stages to the coll1

```
db.coll1.aggregate([
       { $match: { ... } },
       { $lookup:{
           from: "coll2",
           localField: "_id",
           foreignField: "_id",
           as: "coll2"
         }
       }
      // followed by other stages
       //last stage being $merge
        { $merge : { into: "coll3", on: "_id"} }
    ])
```

So, my query is:

1. While the aggregation is in progress, is it possible the underlying collection, in this case `coll1`, is allowed to be modified/updated ?  In either case, please help to understand how it works (went through mongoDb docs, but could not understand)
2. How does it write the final `coll3` ? In sense, does it write all in one shot or one document as it finish the pipeline ?
3. In regards to `spring-data-mongodb`, I am successfully able to call  `mongoOperation.aggregate()` for the above aggregation pipeline, but it returns `aggregationResult` object with Zero `mappedResults`.( When checked in db, coll3 is getting created).
   Does `$merge` not return any such details ?

I am using mongoDb 4.2

Comment: As per the mongoDB documentation aggregate uses read locks for the collection from which you are aggregating. So modify is possible while aggregation is running.
Yes $merge doen't return resultset